# RSA-CRT exponent reduction

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

In the implementation of RSA-CRT, the exponent d is reduced mod p-1 ($d_p = d \bmod {(p-1)}$). The only proof I've found for that, is the following (considering $d = k\varphi(p) + d \bmod {\varphi(p)}$:
$$c^d = c^{k\varphi(n) + d \bmod {\varphi(p)}}$$
$$(c^{\varphi(p)})^k * c^{d\bmod {\varphi(p)}} \equiv (1)^k * c^{d\bmod {(p-1)}} (\bmod p)$$
Source: https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html
So $c^d \equiv c^{d(\bmod(p-1))} (\bmod(p))$ However, I can't see why is the Euler theorem valid here, as c is not granted to be coprime with p (as far as I know). Any hint on this?

Comment: Hint: your $c$ is modulo $p$ when you are using the Euler theorem.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But Euler's theorem only holds when $c$ and $p$ are coprimes, so $(c^{\varphi(p)})^k \equiv 1^k \mod p$ only if c and p are coprimes

Comment: $c~(mod~p)$ is in range $[\![0;p-1]\!]$. Which elements are not coprime to $p$ ?

Comment: c is considered as the ciphertext with the modulus pq. It can be a multiple of p, e.g., 0, p, 2p,..., qp in which case c^d=0 (mod p) and exponent reduction still holds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, the proof isn't precisely correct, because we don't necessarily have $c^{\phi(n)} = 1$, specifically in the case $c \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Here is a more correct approach; we have $c^1 \equiv c \pmod p$ (trivially), and $c^{p-1} \equiv c \pmod p$ for any $c$, prime $p$ (Fermat's little theorem [1]).  By induction, we get $c^{k (p-1) + 1} \equiv c^1 \pmod p$ (for any $k$), and hence $c^{k (p-1) + \ell} \equiv c^\ell \pmod p$.

If we designate $x = k(p-1) + \ell$ for $0 \le \ell < p-1$ (and any $x$ can be put in that form), we have $c^x \equiv c^{x \bmod p-1} \pmod p$, for any $x, c$ and prime $p$; in particular, if $x = d$

---

[1]: The most common expression of Fermat's Little Theorom is that $1 \equiv x^{p-1} \bmod p$ for prime $p$, $x$ relatively prime to $p$.  However, an equivalent formulation (and what Fermat originally stated) is that $x \equiv x^p \bmod p$ for prime $p$, any $x$ - I'm using this alternative formulation.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer also gave some clues for my own proof using transitivity, I'll post it as a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how I didn't realize there are only two cases: $gcd(p, c) = 1$, or $c\equiv 0 \bmod (p)$. Given this, here's the proof I came with.
 For the former, the proof into the question is valid. For the latter, we have:
$$c\equiv 0 \bmod (p)$$ $$c^k\equiv 0 \bmod (p)$$ for any $k$. So, using transitivity:
$$c^k\equiv c\bmod (p)$$
In this case $k=d\bmod (p-1)$